# how to read sheets in an excel file with a for loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

how can I get these several dataframe below in a for loop

```
CTD4_100_ASV = pd.read_excel("verconnec.xlsx",sheet_name="100m-asv").set_index('sign')
CTD4_800_ASV = pd.read_excel("verconnec.xlsx",sheet_name="800m-asv").set_index('sign')
CTD4_1800_ASV = pd.read_excel("verconnec.xlsx",sheet_name="1800m-asv").set_index('sign')
CTD4_2800_ASV = pd.read_excel("verconnec.xlsx",sheet_name="2800m-asv").set_index('sign')
CTD4_3800_ASV = pd.read_excel("verconnec.xlsx",sheet_name="3800m-asv").set_index('sign')
```

I have tried this, but it doesn't work

```
  asvlist=["100m-asv","800m-asv","1800m-asv","2800m-asv","3800m-asv"]
  for i in range(len(asvlist)):
    CTD4_asvlist[i]=pd.read_excel("verconnec.xlsx",sheet_name=asvlist[i]).set_index('sign')
```

Comment: What doesn't work about what you tried? If you got an error message and traceback, please edit the question to include that information.

Comment: looks like you never defined CTD4_asvlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didn't define `CTD4_asvlist`. but there is a cleaner way to do it:

```
asvlist=["100m-asv","800m-asv","1800m-asv","2800m-asv","3800m-asv"]
CTD4_asvlist = [pd.read_excel("verconnec.xlsx",sheet_name=asv).set_index('sign') for asv in asvlist]
```